# Ruby on Rails 4: Extract Oauth2 parameters from token response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, oauth-2.0

I am developing a rails application which uses oauth2 gem to Authenticate a User against Windows azure AD .

I am able to authenticate the user with Azure AD ,but my problem is i need to extract the parameters inside token response.

```
@token = client.auth_code.get_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => "#{APP_URL}/callback", :resource => "#{RES_URL}")
```

I tried `puts @token` in controller but i am getting some Hash values.

```
#<OAuth2::AccessToken:0x000000030ed960>
```

Is it possible to see the contents inside `@token`.

And also can i set headers inside token request.

```
@token = client.auth_code.get_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => "#{APP_URL}/callback", :resource => "#{RES_URL}",:headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can try to use `puts @token.to_yml`
to see the contents of @token